# Regex: Tokenizing fractional numbers, abbreviations and short form of words in a sentence

Tags: javascript, regex

I am currently implementing a Javascript function to tokenize a given sentence into simpler tokens which splits the sentence word-by-word based off of the english language.

I have written a [regular expression](https://regex101.com/r/QaVQYY/1) in Javascript: `/\\[^]|\.+|\w+|[^\w\s]/g`

Based on which I have tried writing a function which takes a sentence as input and tokenizes it by words and returns a Javascript array.

```js
function TokenizeSentence(Sentence)
{
  let tokenizedSentence = new Array();
  let tokenizingRegex = /\\[^]|\.+|\w+|[^\w\s]/g;
  Sentence.replace(tokenizingRegex, (word, offset) => tokenizedSentence.push({
    word: word,
    start: offset,
    end: offset + word.length
  }));
  return tokenizedSentence;

}

let string = `Apply 1/2 day U.S.A leave as I'm away`;

console.log(TokenizeSentence(string));
```

I have an example sentence: `Apply 1/2 day leave as I'm away`, I am unable to figure out that how to take `1/2` and `I'm` as a single token instead of multiple tokens.

**My question is how to treat `1/2` (a fractional number) and `I'm` (short form of words), `U.S.A`(Abbreviations) as a single token?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may add more specific patterns (like `\d+(?:\/\d+)+` to match 1+ digits followed with 1+ sequences of `/` and 1+ digits and `\b\w(?:\.\w)+\b` that matches a single word char followed with 1+ sequences of `.` and a single word char as a whole word) before more generic ones and "expand" `\w+` by adding an optional `(?:'\w+)?` group after it:

```js
function TokenizeSentence(Sentence)
{
  let tokenizedSentence = new Array();
  let tokenizingRegex = /\\[^]|\.+|\d+(?:\/\d+)+|\b\w(?:\.\w)+\b|\w+(?:'\w+)?|[^\w\s]/g;
  Sentence.replace(tokenizingRegex, (word, offset) => tokenizedSentence.push({
    word: word,
    start: offset,
    end: offset + word.length
  }));
  return tokenizedSentence;

}

let string = `Apply 1/2 day U.S.A leave as I'm away`;

console.log(TokenizeSentence(string));
```

**Details**

- `\\[^]` - any escaped sequence (a `\` and any char)
- `|` - or
- `\.+` - 1 or more dots
- `|` - or
- `\d+(?:\/\d+)+` - 1+ digits and then 1+ sequences of `/` and 1+ digits
- `|` - or
- `\b\w(?:\.\w)+\b` - a word boundary, a word char and then 1+ sequences of a dot followed with 1 word char, and then a word boundary (if you plan to only match ASCII uppercase letters, replace `\w` with `[A-Z]`)
- `|` - or
- `\w+(?:'\w+)?` - 1+ word chars followed with an optional sequence of `'` and 1+ word chars
- `|` - or
- `[^\w\s]` - any char other than a word and whitespace char.

Comment: One question that comes to my mind is how to handle abbreviations like the `U.S.A` as its an abbreviation.

Comment: @KunalMukherjee It handles that pattern. See the snippet results.

Comment: So the idea being the generic patterns should be preceded before the more specific ones?

Comment: @KunalMukherjee Yes, because the alternatives are tested from the leftmost to the rightmost, and once an alternative matches, the rest is not tried.

Comment: so the Regex is greedily evaluated, if the more generic pattern matches the word does it terminate the search there? And if I have in case to add more specific patterns to handle specific abbreviations then I should append them to the last?

Comment: Consider this sentence: `my annual salary was 230,000` the $123,000 is treated as a [seperate tokens](https://regex101.com/r/QaVQYY/3) consisting of `123`, `,` and `000`.

Comment: @KunalMukherjee Add it as showed [here](https://regex101.com/r/rS0Jpy/1) or [here](https://regex101.com/r/QgQJbb/1/).

Answer (score 1):

The most simple answer that fits your example would be delimiting the results by spaces:

```
(?<=^| )[^ ]*(?= |$)
```

This returns "Apply", "1/2", "day", "leave", "as", "I'm" and "away".
This, however, doesnt work if you have multiple sentences. But

> which takes a sentence as input

should exclude that.

Description:

1. `(?<=^| )` Positive lookbehind of the beginning or a space
2. `[^ ]*` Any character except a space, 0 to unlimited times (greedy)
3. `(?= |$)` Positive lookahead of line end or a space